# get url to archieve

Tags: php, wordpress

Such code

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
```

produce something like this:

```
<li><a href="http://localhost:81/mysite/?m=201504">MONTH YEAR</a></li>
```

so after click on this my link looks like

http://localhost:81/mysite/?m=201504

*How could I retrieve this m=201504 to print all posts from specified month of year?*

Is it good approach to perform this task like this or maybe I could do it better (how?)

Comment: Well `$_GET['m']` will give you `201504`, does wordpress have a function to use that?

Comment: The link *already should* give you only the posts from the specified month of the year; it's using the `get_month_link()` function which should generate the correct permalink.  I'd suggest turning "Pretty Permalinks" on unless you have a good reason not to do so, then your month links will look something like `local.wordpress.dev/2015/04/`, or however you've defined them in Settings > Permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

[`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is an associative array or URL parameters. You can specifically get the value of `m` with `$_GET['m']`